# in_array() expects to be array error (with array)

Tags: php, arrays

I have this code:

```
<?php
$videoID="gZQc5WGjUJU";
$url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id='.$videoID.'&key=AIzaSyBbwUlQ6qRC7fgEZPO85tsNQg75x01DS14&part=contentDetails';
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($content, true);



$result1= print_r($json[items][0][contentDetails][regionRestriction][allowed]);



if (in_array("DE", $result))
  {
  echo "Match found";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Match not found";
  }
?>
```

The variable `$result1` outputs that:

```
Array
(
    [0] => US
    [1] => IE
    [2] => NZ
    [3] => AU
    [4] => SE
    [5] => AS
    [6] => MX
    [7] => IS
    [8] => GU
    [9] => CA
    [10] => MP
    [11] => LU
    [12] => NL
    [13] => BE
    [14] => NO
    [15] => DK
    [16] => KR
    [17] => GB
    [18] => FI
    [19] => FR
)
1
```

Now I try to check if there is the Value "DE" but it says:

```
Array
(
    [0] => NZ
    [1] => FI
    [2] => LU
    [3] => MP
    [4] => SE
    [5] => MX
    [6] => NO
    [7] => NL
    [8] => FR
    [9] => DK
    [10] => GU
    [11] => IE
    [12] => AS
    [13] => US
    [14] => AU
    [15] => IS
    [16] => GB
    [17] => KR
    [18] => BE
    [19] => CA
)
```

> Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in /customers/1/d/f/50downloads.com/httpd.www/test.php on line 17
>       Match not found

Has someone a idea what the reason could be? The result should be "DE exists" or "DE exists not"

Comment: 1) You use `$result` not `$result1` 2) Do a simple `var_dump($result1);` and see what you have in this variable. Also read the manual page about `print_r()` and look what it returns.

Comment: Where are you assigning `$result`? Your code shows you assigning the string result of `print_r` to `$result1`....

Comment: Remove [print_r](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) from your `result1` assignment.

Comment: Simply `$result = $json[items][0][contentDetails][regionRestriction][allowed];`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this line...

`if (in_array("DE", $result))`

...was meant to be this:

`if (in_array("DE", $result1))`

...except that's a string, since you assigned `$result1` to the result of a `print_r`. As others have said in the comments, you can remove the `print_r` and just set `$result1` to the JSON array.

Comment: OP also probably don't want to assign the return value of `print_r()` but rather the actual array.

Comment: no that wasnt the problem I just mixed it up when i copyed it... it doesnt want to accept the array...

Comment: Thanks. Edited my answer to reflect the actual issue.